# Get-Credential doesn't pass domain

Tags: windows, powershell

I am not sure if this is a right place to ask so apologies if it's not.

I am having a problem with passing credentials to a script using Get-Credential. This cmdlet opens up a window where I enter credentials in the format: domain\username and then password. However having looked at the logs in Event Viewer it looks like domain is not separated and domain\username is treated as a username:

> A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.
>
> Subject:
>     Security ID:        domain\user1
>     Account Name:       user1
>     Account Domain:     domain
>
> Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
>     Account Name:       domain\username
>   Account Domain:

Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the credential object is used in the script you may need to use the method `.GetNetworkCredential()`. A username in for format "DOM\Username" is called a down-level logon name and it's not inaccurate to call the whole thing a username. For that reason the .UserName property on a PSCredential object is the full "DOM\Username" string:

```
c:\> $Credentials.UserName
DOM\User
```

However, the parts are stored seperately and can be accessed with the method `.GetNetworkCredential()`:

```
c:\> $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
User
c:\> $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
DOM
```

If the credentials are passed to a function you didn't write look for parameters for separating the domain and SamAccountName.